# PHP csv field validation

Tags: php, validation, csv

Is it possible to validate all the fields of an uploaded CSV file and will display all errors if any of the validations fail using PHP

For example I have a CSV file uploaded by a user which contains these:

Name,Job,Age
John,Clerk,23
Debra,Manager,32
1A3ce,,40a

Validations will be:

- If Name contains numeric value, display error to the user
- If Age contains non-numeric value, display error th
- If Age is equal or less than zero, display error to the user
- If Job exceeded 15 characters in length, display error to the user
- If any of the fields does not have a value or it is blank, display error to the user

How do you do this? I have little knowledge in PHP and at least a guide on hwo to code this will help me greatly.

Comment: any PHP expert out there? is this possible or no?

Comment: Yes, it is definitely possible. At first you need to read each row from CSV file and append it into php array, then you can process your data in php array using your validation rules. I'm sure you'll be able to find some examples on google to get you started. You can type: 'parse csv file to php array' or something similar.